# Can't get data from request ajax in controller of asp.net web api

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have many problems when i request to controller of api, I think the problems stay with config api.

When I create normal web api which have ValuesController.

- For ValuesController, i create a request ajax as below, i don't need to cross domain, just easy.

  ```
  $.ajax({
    type: "delete",
    url: "http://localhost/api/values/4",
    success: function (data) {
      console.log(data)
    }
  })
  ```

just like above, i can get data normally but

- For a project need to EnableCors in Controller

  ```
  [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
  public class ValuesController : ApiController
  {
      [HttpDelete]
      public HttpResponseMessage Delete([FromUri] Int64 ID1, [FromUri] Int64 ID2)
      { 
      }
  }
  ```

  i can't get data form from ajax request which like below:

  ```
  $.ajax({
       type: 'delete',
       url: 'http://localhost/api/values/1/2',
       crossDomain: true,
       success: function () {
       }
  });
  ```

or

```
$.ajax({
     type: 'delete',
     url: 'http://localhost/api/values/',
     data: {ID1 : 1, ID2: 2},
     crossDomain: true,
     success: function () {
     }
});
```

- i see a difference between web.config of default project api and web.config of monster project api but I don't know how to configure web.config.
- Please, review the web.config of both
- monster project: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3EtIiiIvE-Hb0UwcFZDVHhSUmc/view?usp=sharing
- default one: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3EtIiiIvE-HVTU4cnltNzZJNnM/view?usp=sharing

Thanks. ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Enable cors has nothing to do with the delete problem that you have.

ONe problem here, is that Your pass more than one id in the Uri (fromUri), normally you need to pass one id in the url.

change your delete method to be something like this:

```
[HttpDelete]
public HttpResponseMessage Delete(int id)
{
    // your code goes here
}
```

and for your request this should work

```
$.ajax({
  type: "delete",
  url: "http://localhost/api/values/4",
  success: function (data) {
    console.log(data)
  }
});
```

hope this helps.

Comment: thanks Omar,
i understand your help, but i need to pass two auguments. And for put method, i also want to set two arguments, the one is [FromUri] Int64 Id, other one is [FromBody] Student entity. In the client, i create a ajax request which have { crossDomain: true, data : {name: "new name", ...}, contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" }. When i request with that one, the server don't pass data, while the browser occur No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header'.